# How does flexibility of an algebra imply this identity?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In a paper from Schafer, he mentions that the flexible identity:

$$(xy)x = x(yx)$$

can be "linearized" to become:

$$(xz)y + (yz)x = y(zx) + x(zy)$$

In other words, an flexible algebra (one that satisfies the flexible identity) also always satisfies this equation. However, I'm not sure how to prove this.

The way that this is presented in the paper makes it seem like this is the case for any algebra, but the paper is mostly concerned with algebras over fields, so perhaps that is required. However, even with those conditions, I'm not sure how to prove it.

I'm also not really sure what he means when he says to "linearize" the identity.

So how should this proof go?

Comment: Just linearize the equation. You'll obtain $(x,y,z)+(z,y,x)=0$ for the associators. For a detailed proof see [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=Z1D2BwAAQBAJ&pg=PA8&lpg=PA8&dq=linearize+identity+for+flexible+algebra&source=bl&ots=VroHK_9fcN&sig=ACfU3U0an-ZLzu6jG41s9_Qi9P6pZGnWBA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj07enmp5XoAhVsMewKHfdnAQcQ6AEwAnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=linearize%20identity%20for%20flexible%20algebra&f=false).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Like I said, I don't really know what it means to "linearize" the identity. All that link says is to linearize the identity, without really saying what that means, which is the same as the paper I'm reading.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Ah, I scrolled through the book a bit more, and found where they said what it meant to linearize the equation (though vaguely). But yeah, your answer is very clear, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituting $x+z$ for $x$ in $(xy)x=x(yx)$ we obtain
$$
(xy)x+(zy)x+(zy)z+(zy)z=x(yx)+x(yz)+z(yx)+z(yz)
$$
where the terms $(xy)x$ and $x(yx)$ cancel, as well as $(zy)z$ and $z(yz)$. This gives
$$
(zy)x-z(yx)=x(yz)-(xy)z,
$$
or
$$
(x,y,z)+(z,y,x)=0.
$$
Renaming $x,y,z$ appropriately gives your identity.